# Multiple radGrids with radWindows

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radwindow

I have 3 radGrids in 1 page and I want to popUP a radWindow for every one when I double click on a row.

I use this 2 javascript function:

```
function RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs) {
            alert("it was dblclicked");
            sender.get_masterTableView().editItem(eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical());
            alert("pass rowdbl");
        }

function onPopUpShowing(sender, args) {
            alert("reach onPopUpShowing");
            args.get_popUp().className += " popUpEditForm";
        }
```

I make the radGrids and at Client setting I put the functions:

```
<ClientSettings>
    <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" OnPopUpShowing="onPopUpShowing" />
</ClientSettings>
```

The problem is that for first Grid it Opens the RadWindow , but for the next 2 it doesn't reach the OnPopUpShowing function

In code behind I write this in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
            rdCompanyUsers.MasterTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.PopUp;
            rdRights.MasterTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.PopUp;
            rdDivision.MasterTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.PopUp;}
```

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your exact javascript and the markup below all functionality is what you were trying to achieve.  The only difference is not setting the properties on the grid in Page_Load.  What you showed should work just fine, though.  I suspect there are inconsistencies between your grid declarations or perhaps your datasources have issues.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataSourceID="sdsGrids">
        <MasterTableView EditMode="PopUp"></MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" OnPopUpShowing="onPopUpShowing" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataSourceID="sdsGrids">
        <MasterTableView EditMode="PopUp"></MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" OnPopUpShowing="onPopUpShowing" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataSourceID="sdsGrids">
        <MasterTableView EditMode="PopUp"></MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" OnPopUpShowing="onPopUpShowing" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsGrids" runat="server" ConnectionString="..." SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM ..."></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```